# Django user not in request object when running tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, request

I am running a test that logs a user in, sends some POST data, and analyzes the response. While I could hardcode the User information, I don't understand why I can't access the `user` object from the `request` object. Here is what my test looks like:

```
class CompleteGuidedSetupTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username='test@test.test', password='testtest')

    def test_complete_guided_setup_defaults(self):
        response = self.client.post('/url', {
            'data': data
        })

        # reponse.request.user doesn't work either
        user = response.request['user']
```

I've also tried accessing the user object somewhere on `self.client` but it doesn't appear to exist. There must be some way to access it.

Also, the view that this is calling doesn't render to a template so it isn't in the template context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django docs state that [`response.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.client.Response.request) is the response data that simulates the test. That's not the same as the `request` object used in the view, therefore you can't access the `user` in that way.

The test client does not store the user, it stores a cookie that indicates that it is logged in as that user.

In your test method or `setUp` method, you can fetch the user from the database with:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='test@test.test')
```

Comment: Okay, I thought of that but wasn't sure if that really was the best way to do it. Thanks!